# Convert eregi to preg_match - what is Unknown modifier 'F'?

Tags: php, regex

Trying to convert the following two eregi statements to their preg counterparts:

```
eregi("/F \(([^)]*)\)",$In,$DataOut);

eregi("/T \(([^)]*)\) /V \(([^)]*)\)",$In,$DataOut);
```

So I tried adding in delimiters:

```
preg_match("//F \(([^)]*)\)/",$In,$DataOut);
```

Unfortunately this does not work and produces Unknown modifier errors. Can I get help on what the preg versions of these two expressions might be?

Comment: have you tried `"/\/F \(([^)]*)\)/"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You cannot use the character you chose as a delimiter inside your regex. Escape any occurrence of that character with a backslash (`\`):

```
preg_match("/\/F \(([^)]*)\)/",$In,$DataOut);
```

You can also choose any other delimiter. If you use another character as a delimiter, you won't have to escape the `/` (since it's not the delimiter):

```
preg_match("!/F \(([^)]*)\)!",$In,$DataOut);
```